# Postprocess input field after submit

Tags: meteor

I'am building an application with Meteor. I use autoform, but I want to postprocess some inputfields after submit: add leading zeros to a number when converting to a string ( 20 -> "00020" ), change currency values to integers ( $ 20 -> 2000 or $ 21.34 -> 2134 ). I do not see how to do that. Can anybody help me with this? My issue is with triggering the postprocessing. Some examples would be great.
Regards, Roel

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

add a before hook to your form

From: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks:

> The before hooks are called after the form is deemed valid but before
>   the submission operation happens. (The submission operation depends on
>   the form type.) These hooks are passed the document or modifier as
>   gathered from the form fields. If necessary they can modify the
>   document or modifier.

somewhere in your client code where it will be loaded only once, add:

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  myFormId: {
     before: {
       // Replace `formType` with the form `type` attribute to which this hook applies
       formType: function(doc) {
       // Potentially alter the doc
       doc.foo = 'bar';

       // Then return it or pass it to this.result()
       //return doc; (synchronous)
       //return false; (synchronous, cancel)
       //this.result(doc); (asynchronous)
       //this.result(false); (asynchronous, cancel)
     }
  }      
});
```